# AWS Cross Account Access - Invalid Bucket policy issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Am trying to grant the cross account access for S3 bucket to work with lambda function . In that case , first trying assign appropriate bucket policy for both source and target buckets based on the following link .

```
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/
```

Source Bucket Policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::777777777:role/Staff"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucktet-testing-lambda/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucktet-testing-lambda"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Target Policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:: 777777777:role/Staff"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucktet-testing-lambda/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucktet-testing-lambda"
        ]
    }]
}
```

But in Target bucket policy is telling , *Policy has invalid resource*. Can you please help me on this .

Comment: "Target Policy" is for lambda execution role?

Comment: yes. You are right

Comment: There is no need for a Bucket Policy on the Source bucket. Instead, necessary permissions should be granted in the IAM Role that is assigned to the AWS Lambda function.